# git and hardlink in linux

Tags: linux, git, zsh

I have a git repo *test*, and a file (zsh config file), and

```
ln ~/.zshrc test/zshrc
```

then I changed .zshrc file,the zshrc file in git repo didn't change,is that git cannot deal with hardlink?

if so, how can I use git to manage these dotfiles?any suggestion

Comment: For sure if the files have different content then they are not hardlinked together. Something broke the link. It could be git (when you were changing branches or something) or something else, I don't know. You can check the inode number or both files with `ls -li` to verify if they're hardlinked or not. Use that to find out at what moment the files became unlinked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make¹ hard links outside a git repository. You have several choices:

- Make `~/.zshrc` a symbolic link to `my-home-git-checkout/zshrc`.
- Keep a git checkout in your home directory.
- Copy the file from your git checkout to your home directory, perhaps automatically upon a commit or checkout.

¹  <sub>Yeah, ok, quibble: you can't *keep*.</sub>

Comment: Last solution should be not “upon a commit”, but “upon an update (checkout)”. And in this case it does not matter whether files are to be automatically copied or hardlinked.

Comment: @ZyX Good point about the checkout, but why not upon a commit as well? If that git repository is where you typically edit the files, you'd rarely checkout.

Comment: Does git overwrite files on commit? If yes, why?

Comment: @ZyX Ah, I think I get your point: if you keep hard links, then you only need to recreate them after a checkout (or reset or a number of other operations), not after a commit. I was suggesting a different mode where you make copies, and update the copies when you push a new version; I admit that if you're going to do that, there's not that much point in making `~` a git checkout directly.

Comment: I do not see `post-reset` hook in `git help hooks`. The only other relevant hook is `post-receive` I believe, but who does push to local repositories? Especially when `cd 1 && git push 2` is not equivalent (worse, it can fail with non-bare repositories) to `cd 2 && git pull 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Git always assumes that he is a only owner of a file inode.
So git checkout just breaks all hard links.

Comment: It does not exactly break them up, it just does not record which files share an inode. What git does record however is that the two (at least at one point in time) have the same contents and optimize storing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following script into `/path/to/repo/.git/hooks/post-checkout` (this file must be executable):

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/ln -sf /path/to/repo/zshrc $HOME/.zshrc
```